# Built an array but can't figure to the linking code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Okay so I've built this array but I would like it so when they type their post code into the "post code" text box that it reads the array and if their post code is within the array it adds 2 to the amount/ "total" text box.... how would I go about this as I've been stuck for about 2 weeks now....? Any help is appreciated! thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Post Code</b><input type="text" myfunction()">
    <p>
    <b>Total: &pound; </b><input name="amount" size=8 value="0">
    </p>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var postcode = ["ZE", "KW","IV","HS","AB","DD","PH","PA","FK","KY","G","BT","IM,"GY","JE","EH","ML","KA"];
        var a = postcode.indexOf("CV","LE");
        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = a;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have it populate the input like an auto complete? like this? https://jsfiddle.net/57btpa1x/5/

Comment: No, so basically when they type in the Post Code e.g. ZE17 7LY it reads the first two letters in the text box and if they are within the array it adds £2.00 to the total.....? does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. You should do that on the server side however, as anyone who knows how to open the developer console would be able to change the price they pay for a product!

Comment: oh.... is there any way of stopping that from happening as the server side basically doesn't exist......?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the code you have provided is on the Front end, this means it is downloaded and executed on the client browser which means it is at the mercy of the client.

Comment: @GeorgeGibson nope, JS validation alone is not enough, server-side validation will always be required. Everything clientside can be copied / modified and used to resend fake or invalid requests.

Comment: okay so I'm guessing PHP is going to have to be involved to make this happen? would I be able to use the server I'm hosting from to allow me to do this? and if so i have no idea about PHP at all.....?

Comment: You will need to check with your host provider to see what servers they support. Once you know, go through a few tutorials about passing data from the front end to the back end as well as connecting to a database and you're good to go :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Actually just a quick question....

Comment: I'm using world pay as a payment process and this is going on their form they provided me to go onto the webpage so does that mean if I added it into there it would still be insecure or would they have security measures on the form they've provided me to stop the change of price using developer tools possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typos in the above code.  I have assumed that first two letters of the pincode are mentioned in the array.  Following is the code that I have come up with. Hope it helps..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<b>Post Code</b><input name="postcode" type="text" onblur="myFunction(this.value);">
<p>
<b>Total: &pound; </b><input id="amount" name="amount" size=8 value="0">
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(pc) {
    var postcode_arr = ["ZE", "KW","IV","HS","AB","DD","PH","PA","FK","KY","G","BT","IM","GY","JE","EH","ML","KA"];

    var firsttwo = pc.substr(0,2);
    firsttwo = firsttwo.toUpperCase();
    //alert(firsttwo);

    var a = postcode_arr.indexOf(firsttwo);
    if(a!= -1) {
        var amt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);
        amt +=2;
        document.getElementById("amount").value = amt;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;


}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```